# How to add Virtual host on ec2 wiith Apache 2.4.18?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I'm trying to domain to point specific document root of EC2 instance.
I've set Route 53 and and also set DNS to domain. Now domain points fine.
I have also added host to host file of server.
Now I would like to add following code to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.
I used to do same with Apache 2.2.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xyz
        ServerName xyz.com
</VirtualHost>
```

But When I open `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` it seems too small file Though I have added same to `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and same it and restart Apache with `service httpd restart`.

Would anyone suggest me how can I add it?

Answer (score 2):

I added following code to at the bottom of `add following code to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.com
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xyz
        <Directory /var/www/html/xyz>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Save file and restart Apache as it will be effective once you restart the server with `service httpd restart`.